# Programmatically changing Linux IP address permanently

Tags: linux, command-line, ip-address

Is there a way to permanently change the IP address of a linux based system programmatically? I am working on an ARM based device (in some remote location) with Linux and have to change the IP address on user request. There is no possibility to go onsite and change the configuration file.

I have used following command, but it only changes the IP address temporarily.

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.55 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

The changes are lost on next restart of device. So any suggesstions for permanent changing through command or C code? I have also looked at the [this url](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/10/change-hostname-ip-address) but it is also without help:

Comment: First figure out where the IP configuration is stored (if you know the particular Linux distro that's used, people can probably help you further with that) - then rewrite that config file, and possibly use a distro specific command to apply it.

Comment: Thanks @nos, on my distro, the network configuration is at /etc/network/interfaces. Do I need to rewrite this whole file programmatically? If yes then what about the other content?

Comment: Yes, you need to rewrite that file, and you'll need to keep any content that you're not changing.